# How to use a tensorflow graph in opencv c++?

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to load a pre-trained tensorflow graph into OpenCV and use to detect the class name of a new image provided by the user.
This example seems to work but gives the same class name for every image.(strange)
https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/dnn/samples/tf_inception.cpp

Comment: Hi sir! Did you find any solution for this? I also have this question. Thanks!